# Simulator / Emulator Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hi I am going to make an app with `bluetooth` low energy. And i have problem i have not `BLE` device. Do you know some `emulator` BLE? or How to switch normally `bluetooth` to BLE on my Mac or Android device? I tried find something on google but i didn't find anything ...

Comment: You can build an application that uses core Bluetooth on MacOS to act as a BLE peripheral as long as your mac has a BLE chipset.

Comment: Have you seen AltBeacon's sample Android app?  https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference.  It has a TimedBeaconSimulator.java to do just that.